# Find values of $\alpha$ for $ f:\left[0,1\right]\rightarrow\left[0,1\right] $ such that $ f\left(c\right)=\alpha\cdot c$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

I'm having a bit of trouble with a homework question. Here it is:

Let there be a function that $ f:\left[0,1\right]\rightarrow\left[0,1]\right]
 $ a continuous function.
For what values of $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ will there be a $c \in \left[0,1\right] $ such that $ f\left(c\right)=\alpha\cdot c$

I just can't fathom how I'm supposed to come up with values for $\alpha $ when the function is not defined for me (as in I don't have an equation for it).

Any hint?

Thanks

Comment: This is a weird question, or I'm misunderstooding something: it is always true that $\;f(x)=c_xx\;$ for **any** real function, continuous or not, defined in $\;x\;$ , so I'm guessing this question means $\;\alpha\;$ workds for *all* $\;c\in [0,1]\;$ ...? So they're asking when a continuous function is a linear one?? Hmmm...weird, as they seem to be wanting a condition on the parameter, not the function itself.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I don't understand, I'm guessing that they want either to find an arbitrary value for alpha (like 1 for instance) or find a range for which the condition is met (for instance $0<\alpha<1$). Problem is I have no idea what I'm supposed to do if the function isn't fully given to us.

Comment: Is this from some book you can give a reference to?

Comment: Nope, not that I know of. Its a homework assignment that as far as I know was not taken from any book

Comment: And is the wording accurate? I'd say it makes no sense since for **any** $\;\alpha\in\Bbb R\;$ , the function $\;f(x):=\alpha x\;$ obviously fulfills the condition... Something seems to be twisted here...

Comment: It isn't for any $\alpha$ its **for which** values of $\alpha$ though

Comment: Exactly my point, @user475680 . That's why I think the question, worded as it is, makes no sense, unless I am missing something here.

Comment: Woops just noticed a small mistake, the function is defined as $f:\left[0,1\right]\rightarrow\left[0,1\right]
 $

Comment: Yes, that's what you wrote from the beginning, didn't you? At least that's what I understood all along.

Comment: I accidentally wrote f:[0,1]->[1,0] instead, but yeah it doesn't change too much in terms of the understanding of what they want me to do

Comment: That has no bearing, at least with me, about this question's problematic wording, @user

Comment: You can show that for any $f$, the admissible values of $\alpha$ make an interval. It is closed and unbounded on exactly one side if $f(0) \neq 0$, and can be any interval (even degenerated to a point) if $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: I am bit surprised by the comments. The question as worded currently is without any ambiguity (maybe the version before edit had some issues) and it has been provided with an excellent answer which no one seems to have noticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple real analysis appoach is sufficient for this.However, I think a more graph-like approach is much better for your develop.
**The Approach:**

Image $f$ as a curve $y=f(x)$ , that  curve is in $Oxy$ and must sasitfy these:
i) $f$ connects 2 point in line $x=0$ and $x=1$ respectively
 
ii)$f$ lies entirely in the cell $[0;1]\times[0;1]$
iii) (Not necessary for this problem) each line $x=c(0=c=1)$ cuts $f$ at exactly 1 point.

Thus, the question of problem is to find which $\alpha$ so that $y=\alpha x$ and $f$ intersect forall all curve $f$ sastify i) and ii)
.
(Try to draw yourself some lines and curves , to know clearlier  )

We find that the line $y=\alpha x$ devides the cell in two parts .
Thus, the question of problem occurs if and only if  in that cell,line $x=1$ and $x=0$ lies in two different parts( not include endpoints) which are devided by y=\alpha x  
(Again, try draw some, it's good for anyone's knowledge)

Which equivalent to $\alpha \ge 1 $ .

In case, you want an alternative proof:
**Another proach**
For $\alpha <1$ , we choose the function $f_1(x)=1$, thus we easily see that $f_1(x)>\alpha alpha \forall x \in [0;1]$.Hence, these $\alpha$ do not sasity the conclusion.

For $\alpha \ge 1$ ,  $f(x) \in [0;1]$, therefore $ [ f(0)-\alpha.0][f( 1) -\alpha.1] \le 0$.
Due to the continuousness of $ f(x)-\alpha x$, we imply the conclusion.

Comment: Excellent answer !! +1, I am surprised why this answer was not noticed by many.